# Edge Browser-@supports for SCSS throws error

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, scss-lint

I have an angular2 application where I am using scss for styling. I need to fix a small alignment issue only in Microsoft Edge. I have written the css like-

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
    .checkbox {
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
}
```

but when I hover on @supports  it gives me error-

```
[scss] at-rule unknown
```

Any idea why is this not working.

Comment: version of sass? Do you use Stylint?

Comment: Cant find out the version. But I am using angular cli which compiles my scss to css. Node-6.7.0 and npm- 3.10.3

Comment: Could you try this hack:  `.checkbox { @supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) { padding-top: 10px;}}`?

Comment: does not work :(